# window.hasOwnProperty('innerHeight') returns false in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, sinon

I'm facing a strange problem in stubbing out innerHeight property on the window object in a unit test running on Firefox.

`window.hasOwnProperty('innerHeight')` returns `false` (only in firefox) which is expected as per the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty MDN [docs] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).  However, what object is the innerHeight property defined on?

This fails (as there is not a prototype) property on window?

```
window.prototype.hasOwnProperty('innerHeight');
```

The main reason I want to know is to stub the property out during a test with sinon which works in chrome but fails in firefox because firefox reports this property as not belonging to the window object.  So what object does it belong to?

Comment: `'innerHeight' in window` returns true in everything but IE8 and down, and is the proper way to check for that property.

Comment: It's `Window.prototype`, I think

Comment: @bfavaretto Yeah that's the one, thanks - put it as the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prototype` property belongs on the `Window` constructor. But I'd use `'innerHeight' in window` as suggested by adeneo, since that would check the `window` object and its prototype chain.